# Visual Studio Typescript Errors Angular 7 - Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, angular7

I'm getting the following errors in VS.Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts

I've got the TypeScriptToolsVersion set to latest which has been mentioned as a possible fix in other answers to similar questions.

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

[image: Errors]

I'm using VS 2017. I've added the path of environment variables to TypeScript\3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to download the latest SDK for Visual Studio.

Downloading it fixed the issue.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258